# Android SQL Query syntax

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I use this java class to create a database:

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "grades.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABELLA_RICETTE = "TabellaRicette";
public static final String COL_ID="ColonnaId";
public static final String COL_NOME="ColonnaNome";
public static final String COL_TIPO = "ColonnaTipo";
public static final String COL_IMMAGINE = "ColonnaImmagine";
public static final String COL_ATTRIBUTI="ColonnaAttributi";
public static final String COL_INGREDIENTI = "ColonnaIngredienti";
public static final String COL_DIFFICOLTA="ColonnaDifficolta";
public static final String COL_DESCRIZIONE="ColonnaDescrizione";

public DBhelper(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql_tab = "create table " + TABELLA_RICETTE + "( " +
            COL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            COL_NOME + " text not null, " +
            COL_TIPO + " text not null, " +
            COL_IMMAGINE + " text not null, " +
            COL_ATTRIBUTI + " text not null, " +
            COL_INGREDIENTI + " text not null, " +
            COL_DIFFICOLTA + " text not null, " +
            COL_DESCRIZIONE + " text not null " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(sql_tab);
}

@Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

I use this function to obtain all the information in the database:

```
public Cursor get_all() {
    return getWritableDatabase().query(TABELLA_RICETTE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Now i would make a more specific query, selecting all the element that has a particular `String s1` in `COL_TIPO` and `String s2` in `COL_DIFFICOLTA`.

I tried to write something, but maybe i am wrong in syntax too.

Can you help me with this function?

```
public Cursor get_something(String s1,String s2) {
   String whereClause="COL_TIPO=? AND COL_DIFFICOLTA=?";
   String[] whereArgs=new String[] {s1,s2};
   return getWritableDatabase().query(TABELLA_RICETTE,null,null,whereClause,whereArgs,null,null,null);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COL_TIPO` is not the name of a column but the name of the symbol that contains the name of the column.

You have to put the symbols' values into the SQL string:

```java
String whereClause = COL_TIPO+"=? AND "+COL_DIFFICOLTA+"=?";
```